# Ajax Post containing list of objects to Spring MVC Controller

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, spring, model-view-controller

How do i post a list of objects from javascript to Spring MVC Controller?  I can post arrays, objects, but not a combination of the 2.  This is my code below.

Javascript:

```
     var utilData = getTableData();
    // Sending data over to server
    console.log(utilData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "saveUtilData2.html",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {utilArray: utilData},
        success: function(data){
            alert("save was sucessful");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Save wasn't successful");
        }
    });
```

Spring Controller (tried changing utilData to String[] and object[] ... both didnt work:

```
         @RequestMapping(value="/saveUtilData2.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveUtilData2(@RequestParam("utilArray") String[] utilData, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println("Util Save Data method 2");

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("util"); 
    return mv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @Requestbody instead of Requestparam